# Sending a gridview selected row with session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, row

I want to send a gridview selected row in C# with Session.

I try to save the row like this:

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["try"] = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        Response.Redirect("ProjectInformation.aspx");
    }
```

Then , in ProjectInformation.aspx i want to retrieve the row from the Session but i dont know how to do it .
can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this in the pageload of your redirected page..

```
GridViewRow a = (GridViewRow)Session["try"];
```

Give Header file `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`

Comment: i try that but i cant create GridViewRow.
Error 5 The type or namespace name 'GridViewRow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)